# Sign up with a Phone number using Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm looking for a way how can a User sign up just using a Phone number instead of Username and Password ?

and How can I access to the User class data like any other class, I wasn't able to make queries on User class ?

```
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query2 = ParseQuery.getQuery("user"); 
                     query2.whereEqualTo("phone", "0624982192");
                     query2.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() 

                     {

                       public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) 
                       {

                         if(e == null)
                         {

                      //To do if the phone number is found

                         }
                         else
                         {
                           if(e.getCode() == ParseException.OBJECT_NOT_FOUND)
                           {
                            // To do if the phone number is not found
                           }
```

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: What is the actual code you used to query the User class? Please post it here in your question (not as a comment). And if it triggers an error in logcat, please post that in your question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still looking for the best way to do this and for any future visitors, here is the "Parse way" ! ;)
http://blog.parse.com/announcements/phone-based-login-can-you-dig-it/

Complete with an example iOS app based on Twilio to understand the underlying methods :
https://github.com/parseplatform/anyphone

It's based on Cloud code, with a random number (sent by sms) and a secret token to use as a password. And the phone number as username.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the initialisation of your ParseQuery is wrong for a User object. 
It should be something like this.

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
```

For a full example of querying a User check here : https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#users-querying

In terms of signing up using a phone number, I do not think that Parse has any functionality to do this explicitly and if you are planning on getting the user to enter there phone number then this could be slightly unsecure as any user could enter a random phone number and gain access to someone elses account. However if this is what you want to do then I would suggest you create a new class, rather than using the pre-defined User class. This way you would be able to create your own structure and define your own security for the class.

Answer (score 0):

I won't recommend using just the phone number to sign up , but you can do it in the following ways using parse.

You have to use Parse Cloud code to create a onSave hook to verify that the phone numbers stored in the database are unique , otherswise multiple users might access a single "user" , for more details --> https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#cloud_code

OR

You have to query the phone field before signup to verify if the phone number exists in the database then use an intent to take the user to the required activity.

Edit: Like @JayDev suggested , create your own class rather than the user class